# How to show the following identity

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose we have two functions:
$$
\tag 0 g_{1}(t, m, l) = \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(lx)\cos(my)}{t - \cos(2x) - 2\cos(x)\cos(y)}dxdy,
$$
$$
\tag {0'} g_{2}(t, m, l) = \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(lx)\cos(my)}{t - \cos(2x) - 2\cos(x)\cos(3y)}dxdy
$$
Here $m, l$ are positive integer numbers.

One scientific paper claims that 
$$
\tag 1 g_{2}(t,m,l) = g_{1}\left(t, \frac{m}{3}, l \right),
$$
but I don't see how this can be true; especially I don't understand which transformation I have to perform to see this equality. For example, for $m =0$ $(1)$ provides the statement that
$$
g_{2}(t, 0, l) = g_{1}(t, 0,l)
$$
which seems to be incorrect.

Could you help me?

Precisely, an article is [this](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/13/9/10.1063/1.1666155#) one, and the statement $(1)$ is the direct consequence of Eq. $(3.13)$, which relates expression given by Eq. $(3.5)$ with the one which is given by Eq. $(2.2a)$. They coincide with my expressions $(0), (0')$ up to simple coordinate transformation, which isn't relevant, up to multiplier in Eq. $(3.5)$, and up to the redefinition of constant $t \to \frac{4t^{2} - 3}{2}$ in $(3.5)$, which aren't relevant.

Comment: @tired : yes, thank You, I'll correct.

Comment: it would be nice if you could manage to find a final version of your question instead of editing it every few minutes

Comment: If $m$ is a multiple of $3$ then the equality is easy to understand.  Where it is not trivial is when $m$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @tired : sorry, I've missed some parts when read an article. The present version seems to be correct.

Comment: @RonGordon : but what to do with equality $g_{2}=g_{1}$ when $m = 0$? As for me, it is confusing.

Comment: @RonGordon : according to the text of the article, $m$ may be arbitrary.

Comment: In Eq. (0'), sub $y=u/3$.  Then $u \in [-3 \pi.3 \pi]$ and the integral has a factor of $1/3$ in front.  However,, now the integral covers $3$ periods, so it is $3$ times as large and thus the $3$ cancels the $1/3$ and you have equality...but only when $m/3$ is an integer.

Comment: @RonGordon because this integral seems to be related to lattice Fouriertransforms i'm almost sure that we can view $m$ as integer

Comment: @tired : $m$ is integer, but $\frac{m}{3}$ seems to be non-integer also.